# How to pass respective row data to component using *ngFor+angular4

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have html like below. Need Help. I am not expertise in Angular.

```
<tbody>       
        <tr  *ngFor="let data of employeeFilterLists">
            <td>{{data.Code}}</td>
            <td (click)="selectEmployee('{{data.Code}}')">{{data.FirstName}} {{data.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Salary}}</td>
        </tr>       
</tbody>
```

Now, I have written component method to catch value to call another component from method.

```
selectEmployee(mdData:string){
  console.log("Choose Model...."+ mdData);
}
```

I am getting below error.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 16 in [selectEmployee('{{data.Code}}')] in ng:///AppModule/EmployeeComponent.html@16:16 ("  <tr  *ngFor="let data of employeeFilterLists">
            <td>{{data.Code}}</td>
            <td [ERROR ->](click)="selectEmployee('{{data.Code}}')">{{data.FirstName}} {{data.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{"): ng:///AppModule/EmployeeComponent.html@16:16
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 16 in [selectEmployee('{{data.Code}}')] in ng:///AppModule/EmployeeComponent.html@16:16 ("ists">
            <td>{{data.Code}}</td>
            <td (click)="selectEmployee('{{data.Code}}')">[ERROR ->]{{data.FirstName}} {{data.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{{data.Salary}}</td>
        </tr>
"): ng:///AppModule/EmployeeComponent.html@16:58
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 16 in [selectEmployee('{{data.Code}}')] in ng:///AppModule/EmployeeComponent.html@16:16 ("(click)="selectEmployee('{{data.Code}}')">{{data.FirstName}} {{data.LastName}}</td>
            <td>[ERROR ->]{{data.Salary}}</td>
        </tr>

"): ng:///AppModule/EmployeeComponent.html@17:16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the {{}} in selectEmployee method,

This goes like this:

```
<td (click)="selectEmployee(data.Code)">{{data.FirstName}} {{data.LastName}}</td>
```

Hope this helps!